# Cloud Functions deploy produces annoying "path is deprecated" warning with no indication from firebase about a replacement

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud functions database.d.ts has the following comment which throws warnings in my IDE and when I deploy my project:

```
/** @deprecated Removed in next major release to match Web SDK typings. */ 
path: string;
```

In many of my cloud functions, I create dictionaries with the keys being paths to realtime database nodes whenever I want to update entries.

This is the exact behavior I need and works without any issues. However, every time I deploy my cloud functions I'm greeted with over 50 warnings that:

```
path is deprecated: Removed in next major release to match Web SDK typings.
```

The terminal call that creates these warnings is:

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
```

Without the path variable, I'd have to create a custom function to create a path from the DatabaseReference's key and parent keys. That sounds absurd. Is this possibly a lint issue?

There's nothing to indicate in the documentation that they're removing the path variable, and I hate seeing this warning spammed every time I deploy my functions. Is this a legitimate warning, and if so, is there a replacement way of getting the path from a DatabaseReference built into the sdk?

Comment: do you use path("path/to/file") or /path/to/file?

Comment: no it's not that type of path, it's a firebase custom path variable in their project files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path property deprecated in version 9+ of the node SDK –

Try do a ref.toString() and remove the base URL

Consider:

```
var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");

adaRef.toString()
```

Will print the full URL: https://firebaseio.com/users/ada
So to just get the path, you substring it out of there. Two ways of doing that are:

```
adaRef.toString().substring(firebase.database().ref().toString().length-1)
```

Or:

```
adaRef.toString().substring(adaRef.root.toString().length-1)
```

both will print /users/ada

Looking at this pull request[[1]](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/830) on the Admin SDK open-source repo, it looks like the path property was deprecated to create type compatibility between the JavaScript/web SDK and the Node.js Admin SDK.

The client-side JavaScript SDK for Firebase Realtime Database never had a path property. The way to get the path has always been to call toString() explicitly, or to include the reference in a string concatenation.